# Guardar imagen en galería - Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, imagen, xamarin

Estoy intentando descargar las imágenes que veo en un `ImageView`, la imagen se carga por medio de una `URL` y la carga se auxilia de `FFImageLoading` Nuget.

He revisado el evento paso a paso y no hay ningún error o excepción, incluso me muestra el mensaje de "Listo" cuando ya finalizo el evento, pero no me descarga la imagen.

El evento de `DescargarImagen()` se gatilla con el evento `OnClick()` del ImageView de esta forma:

```
                            string vUrl = "https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190905/ourmid/pngtree-background-template-for-advertising-png-image_1723078.jpg"; 
                            // Url de prueba
                            System.Uri myURI = new System.Uri(vUrl);
                            
                            DescargarImagen(myURI);
        
                            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Listo", ToastLength.Short).Show();
```

Evento de descarga:

```
public String DescargarImagen(Uri URL)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            string folderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Images", "temp");
            string fileName = URL.ToString().Split('/').Last();
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, e.Result);
            };

            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(URL);

            return filePath;   

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inténtalo de esta forma:

```
public void DownloadImage(string URL)
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[e.Result.Length];
                bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data
                string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

                var partedURL = URL.Split('/');
                string localFilename = partedURL[partedURL.Length - 1];
                string localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
                File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // writes to local storage

                MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Application.Context, new string[] { localPath }, null, null);
            };
            var url = new Uri(URL);
            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);
        }
```

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias.